# How to access svg element with dynamic id in link function of AngularJS template directive?

Tags: angularjs, dom, svg, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to reuse a template directive in a ng-repeat loop. I'm passing down to the directive an id which is then used in the template as following:

```
<g id="scaling{{id}}">\
... 
</g>
```

This works perfectly, it gets rendered properly in the final html page. Now the thing is that I'm trying to select the element above with the dynamically set unique id in the link function of the directive as following in order to set some style attributes:

```
d3.select('#scaling' + scope.id}.
```

However this always returns null. From what I've understood by searching around, this happens because the element is not in the DOM yet when I make this query. How can I work around this? Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found the solution myself. You can add the DOM selection query in a $timeout function, which will only get called after the DOM is rendered.